# WebSphere Process Server insists on using transactions

Tags: transactions, websphere

We have a process in WPS, that does the following:

- There is a web services that gets 10 records
- There is then a process that sends these records to a different web service one at a time

These are just basic WCF web services, they are not WS-* services, so they cannot use a transaction.

For some reason WPS insists on running this as a transaction. The problem we experience is that if these web service calls take too long the transaction timesout.

Is there some way we can stop WPS treating this as a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Process Server are you using and how are you invoking the webservice (in a BPEL micro flow or long running process). Usually webservice calls should not take a long time. If they are taking more than 2 mins, I personally think that the architecture should be revisited. The following are your options:

1. You can try parallel flow activity in BPEL can be used to invoke these Webserivice calls (step 2) in parallel.
2. Make the process a longrunning one. so that you can isolate transactions.
3. This is not recommended but you can try bumping up the transaction timeout to 180 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can disable the transaction (not recommended)

Follow the IBM for details:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v7r0mx/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.wbit.help.advanced.doc%2Fqos%2Ftopics%2Fracts.html